# How to write check_mk manual checks

Tags: python, nagios, check-mk

I have a python scripts which checks for the processes 
    import subprocess

```
s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)
if "cmd.exe" in s:
    if "java.exe" not in str(s):
        print "selenium server is not up"  
    if "FreeSSHDService.exe" not in str(s):
        print "SSH is not up"
    else:
        print "Everything is awesome"
```

I want to add a check on check_mk dashboard, what are the steps to add this check and where I have to up this script.

```
import subprocess

s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)
if "cmd.exe" in s:
    if "java.exe" not in str(s):
       return 2, "selenium server is not up") 
    if "FreeSSHDService.exe" not in str(s):
       return 2, "SSH is not  up"
    else:
        return 0, "Everything is awesome"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm assuming the node you want to check is MS Windows based, in which case I cannot help you much because my expertise is about UNIX and Linux.

This [web link](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_windows.html) will help you to check your Windows based nodes, especially the paragrah `10. Extending the Windows agent`.

In Linux, once the check_mk_agent is installed, there are three ways according to how deep you want to get into the check_mk guts. In Windows I think there are the same methods.

1. As a local service: you copy your python code into the `local` folder, whatever it is located in Windows, and edits the `[global]` section of the `check_mk.ini` configuration file to make run the `py` and `pyc` file name extensions.
2. As a MRPE check: you make your python program print its output according to the [Nagios output check format](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html) and edit the `[mrpe]` section of the `check_ini` configuration file according to [the notes in the paragraph 10.2](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_windows.html). As a disadvantage, the WARNING and CRITICAL values/ranges are fixed in the `check_ini` file -- they cannot be changed in WATO.
3. As a check_mk agent: you turn your python program into a **check_mk agent**. I think this is the most difficult way because each check_mk agent has to have a counterpart definition/declaration/inventory file in the check_mk server in order to be used in WATO and to configure its parameters. I never wrote down one, but if you are keen on, you should read [this guidelines](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_devel_agentbased.html).

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute such script you just need to put it (with the correct rights, chmod +755) in the ~/local/lib/nagios/plugins directory.

Then you have to create a rule from the "host and services parameters -> active checks -> Classical active & passive checks"

Once done, you need to enter the command line "python ~/local/lib/nagios/plugins/nameofyourscript.py"

I am not sure about the output though, still working on it for python scripts.